# Expressing a function as a sum of spherical harmonics

Tags: calculus, spherical-harmonics

I'm asked to express the function $$ f(\theta,\phi) = \sin\theta \left[ \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}\,\cos\phi + i \cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\,\sin\phi  \right] + \sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$ as a sum of spherical-harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$.

So, I have to write $f$ in the form $$ f(\theta,\phi) = \sum_{m,l} a_{ml}Y_l^m(\theta,\phi). $$ I'm not clear on how to get the values for $a_{ml}$. I was thinking on evaluating the integral $$ a_{ml} = \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} Y_l^{m*}(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta \,f(\theta,\phi) d\theta d\phi, $$ where $f(\theta,\phi)$ is written as the first equation, but I'm unable to solve this integral. Ideas?

Also, having $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ means that $l=0,1,2$ or just $l=2$ ?

Comment: a shortcut is to try and write each term of your f as a specific set of spherical harmonics with a constant pulled out. Since they're orthogonal, the integral becomes trivial. look here for clues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#Real_spherical_harmonics